# How to detect partially filled HTML date input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, events, dom-events

Using `input type="date"` on Chrome, client wants to flag a field if date is partially filled, ie: `01/23/yyyy` (but not if it is empty). However, Chrome only seems to fire `input` or `change` if the date is filled out. Also, the actual value of the field remains an empty string.

It may be possible to listen for up/down/digit keypresses after `focus` and then mark the field invalid on `blur` but that's obviously less than ideal.

So, is there an event I'm unaware of that I could use to detect this situation? Or a value I can check that will return `01/23/yyyy`?

Comment: adding a `required` attrib to the input should stop the submit unless it's valid

Comment: We will use our own validation system to flag the field which will prevent submission. I edited the question to clarify. I know how to prevent submission, just not how to detect the situation.

Comment: css: `:invalid, input[type='date']:empty { border-color: red; }`... you can feed the left side to `querySelector()` as well.

Comment: Thanks but we do not want to flag empty dates. Edited question to specify that.

Comment: these are interchangeable parts: ex: `input[type='date']:invalid{ border-color: red; }`, it's the `:invalid` part that you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, nice! All the `required` talk had me thinking you were misunderstanding, but `:invalid` does seem to detect the situation. I will update when I get back to this, but `:invalid` selector looks promising.

Comment: years ago, i believe that `:invalid` would not hit indterminate inputs that weren't required, but modern browsers seem to hit just a bare half-filled date input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:invalid` suggestion from dandavis in the comments worked nicely.

I ended up just adding `$(object).is(':invalid')` to the list of things that trigger an error in our validation and that did the trick.